# The set of all self-inverting functions in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, functions

I had asked a question about self-induced functions a few days ago and would like to discuss again in the topic a bit. We found out that if $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$, then that for an invertible function $g(x)$, the function
\begin{align}
f_g(x) = g^{-1}(f(g(x)))
\end{align}
is also a self-inverting function again. What I am wondering now is whether with the function
\begin{align}
f(x) = \frac{ax+b}{cx-a}
\end{align}
all other self-invertible functions in the space $\,\mathbb{R} \,$ follow, so the set of self-inverting functions is thus completely described.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is self-inverse, i.e. $f(f(x))=x$ on $\mathbb{R}$, you might consider $g(x)=x-f(x)$. Then, $$g(f(x))=f(x)-f(f(x))=-g(x),$$ i.e. $$f(x)=g^{-1}(-g(x)).$$ Wouldn't that be a description of all self-inverse functions using just one, $f(x)=-x$?

Comment: But example:
\begin{align}
g(x) = e^x - r, \hspace{20pt} g^{-1}(x) = \ln(x+r) \hspace{20pt} f(x) = g^{-1}(-g(x)) = \ln(-e^x+2r) 
\end{align}
This is the same with:
\begin{align}
f(x) = \frac{ax+b}{cx-a} = -x + 2r, \hspace{20pt} g(x) = e^{x} \hspace{20pt} g^{-1}(f(g(x)) = \ln(-e^x +2r)\,,
\end{align}
where $a = -1$, $c = 0$, $b = 2r$. So we describe the same set of functions.

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many more functions on $\Bbb R$ that are their own inverse.  Most of them cannot be described.  You can split $\Bbb R$ into sets of one or two elements any way you want.  Having done so, a self-inverse function will take all the elements in single element sets to themselves and take all the elements in two element sets to the other one.

This gives us $2^{\mathfrak c}$ self-inverse functions. Take any partition of $\Bbb R$ into three element sets, of which there are $\mathfrak c$.  We can form a distinct self-inverse function by choosing any collection of one element out of each set, which we can do in $3^{\mathfrak c}$ ways.